# Android CardView behaving differently in 2 Android device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, android-gridlayout, cardview

I've made a Card View GUI containing 6 options and the vertical layout looks good in my 2 devices. However when doing a layout for landscape mode, I see it cropped in one device.

#### Working Device

`Android Version 11`

[image]

#### Not Working Device

`Android Version 9`

[image]

#### Code

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.TestActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:text="@string/main_menu_title"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnCount="3"
            android:rowCount="2"
            android:layout_below="@id/title_view"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">


            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardStart"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtCardStart"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:text="Start"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_start_black_24dp" />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardTest"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:text="Option B"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_camera_alt_24" />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardSettings"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:text="Option C"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp" />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardStats"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:text="Option D"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_insights_black_24dp" />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardContact"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:text="Option E"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_email_24" />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardAbout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:text="Option F"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_info_24" />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </GridLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

The difference in colors is just because I've one phone on Dark mode, while the other not. This is defined by the theme:

```xml
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

What is causing this weird cropping in one phone but not on the other? Is there anything recommended in this case that works on all devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works for you, you could try a constraint layout instead? Just replace the images with your own.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.TestActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/main_menu_title"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardStart"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cardSettings"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cardTest"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardAbout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCardStart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:text="Start"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_chats"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="87dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="305dp" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardTest"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/cardStart"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cardStart"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/cardStart">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:text="Option B"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_chats" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardSettings"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/cardStart"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cardStart"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/cardStart">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:text="Option C"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_chats" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardStats"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/cardAbout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cardAbout"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/cardAbout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:text="Option E"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_chats" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardContact"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/cardAbout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cardAbout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/cardAbout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:text="Option D"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_chats" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardAbout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cardStart"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cardContact"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cardStats"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_view">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:text="Option F"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_chats" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

You get a stretch to fit behavior like this in all devices from 4k tv to a small mobile device.
Screenshots for phone and tablet:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: This is almost perfect. Do you know why on my second phone I'm seeing cropped text: https://imgur.com/a/VX2Vb7T?